# How do I define placeholder variables in a Live Template in Android Studio?

Tags: android, live-templates

Currently, I'm making a live template to initialize recycler views with their associated layout manager and adapter.

I was wondering how I could implement placeholder values (like ${} in eclipse) such that code is clearer.

Example Live Template Code:

```
     = (RecyclerView) findViewById();
    LinearLayoutManager  = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
     = new ;

    .setLayoutManager();
    .setHasFixedSize(true);
    .setAdapter();
```

Desired Live Template Code:

```
    mList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_view);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter();

    mList.setLayoutManager(mLayout);
    mList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that in IntelliJ-IDEA, for live templates, you can define placeholders
using ***$$*** (e.g ***$mList$*** ). After there are such variables present in the Live Template Text, they can be edited by clicking the Edit Variables button(As depicted below). Hope that helps! [image: Intelij LiceTemplate Example]

In order to be able to dynamically set the mList variable click on "Edit Variables" and edit the "mList" variable as depicted in the below image:
[image]

Just after you use the LiveTemplate type "myList" and all the places where the variable was placed will be replaced with your input.

Comment: I've tried this, but when I insert my code, the placeholders are blank, so id get something described in my Example Live template code above.

Comment: I have just edited my response, to also include how to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I couldn't find placeholder for the live template; however, I just wrote in "dummy" variable names such as yourAdapter to indicate they need to be changed.